# Can someone transgress the 3 cardinal sins to save Jews?

Tags: halacha, sin

As we see in the [Megilas Esther Perek 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3?lang=bi) Mordechai didn't bow down to Haman because according to some he had an idol on his neck. However, by him not doing so enraged him to want to kill all the Jews.

So my question is, can someone transgress the three cardinal sins if he thinks by doing so jews won't be killed?

Comment: Yes. We do see that Esther perhaps did that exact thing

Comment: i believe the Malbim talks about this

Comment: Find me that Malbim! Lol

Comment: Chaza"l tell us that the three cardinal sins are yeharev val ya'avor, which indicates that one should die, rather than transgress. What leads you to believe that violating them to save Jewish lives would be permissible ?

Comment: - Save 1,000,000s of jews

Comment: The question seems to assume that Mordechai somehow knew that not bowing would cause Haman to decide to commit genocide against the entire Jewish people rather than just exact revenge against Mordechai. Do you have any basis for this assumption?

Comment: @Moshe well Tosafos and Rashi say that doing yehareg v’al ya’avor for gilui arayos is not necessary for women because in sexual relations, the women is what’s known as קרקע עולם, and she plays a passive role in the act, and we know that for the three cardinal sins, it must be a ma’aseh, so therefore we learn that women are patur from killing themselves if forced into gilui arayos. And Esther is a proof for this- because she slept with Achashverosh. She was able to because of the concept of קרקע עולם (though others say it’s because she was doing it to save the nation)

Comment: I believe the answer is no. Any exceptions you find have an explanation why it was different in that case, (Esther, Yael). You haven't shown that bowing to Haman was idol worship.

Comment: @Jay The way of the world is when you have a bad association with a person of certain sect it makes you think one way about them. So too with Hamans view of Jews due to Mordechai.

Comment: @jay Additionally Haman made an idol on himself/himself (see targum 6:1, See Medresh panim acharim, and megilah 19, Pirkei Devi Eliezer 50 etc). He did so so jews will bow down to Avodah Zara. Once the helig Mordechai didn't bow to him Haman wanted to kill all the Jews (see Medresh Esther 6:10

Comment: @Robev see the classic sources that it was, start with megilah 19

Comment: @CuriousYid That Tosafos and Rashi are for before she went to Achashverosh willingly - Megillah 15a (עד עכשיו באונס ועכשיו ברצון וכאשר אבדתי אבדתי כשם שאבדתי מבית אבא כך אובד ממך). They are coming to justify how it could ever be permitted even b'oness.

Comment: @dov I'm counting on your malbim

Comment: I need to try and find it. I had a shiur which discussed how the Jewish ppl had ta'anos on Mordechai when he told them to not go the feast (at the beginning of the Megillah) as it may create a chillul Hashem as only the Jews wouldn't be represented and might serve to antagonise the king, and then again they told Mordechai off for not bowing to Haman (they would bow whilst praising Hashem in an undertone) - in both instances they claimed they were acting so as to prevent a potential genocide etc.

Comment: The way of the world is that when you have a negative association with an individual you do not then attempt to commit genocide against the entire group regardless of what you think of them. It is easy for you in hindsight to say that obviously Haman would try to kill the entire Jewish nation, but at the time it was actually not the logical outcome.